# YouTube API callback functions are not available when putting them inside DOMContentLoaded's callback

Tags: javascript, html, dom, browser

I've tried to use the Youtube API, and it doesn't work because its callback functions are not available when putting them inside the DOMContentLoaded's callback, and I seek for a detailed explanation for this behavior.

```
// main.js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function () {

const tag = document.createElement('script');
const firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
const recordButton = document.getElementById("btn-record");
const recordedChunks = [];
let youtubePlayer;

//  Setup YouTube API
tag.src = "https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api";
firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);

//  This function creates an <iframe> (and YouTube player)
//  after the API code downloads.
function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
    youtubePlayer = new YT.Player('yt-player', {
        height: '390',
        width: '640',
        videoId: 'g2MKmLiT7sw',
        events: {
            'onReady': onPlayerReady,
            'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange
        }
    });
}
// rest of js code...

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
<title>YT - Karaoke</title>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="yt-player"></div>

    <button id="btn-record"></button>
    <p class="err"></p>

    <audio id="player" src="" controls></audio>

    <script src="main.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The script at https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api expects onYouTubeIframeAPIReady to be a global.

If it isn’t the it is out of scope.

Comment: Why is it expecting that? is it related to the page lifecycle or to the api script?

Comment: The code is in its own script, not inside the function you pass to addEventListener